# Save (not just show) device contact only in device

Tags: contacts, samsung-galaxy-note-3, google-contacts

Device : samsung galaxy note 3 neo
Os : kitkat 442

Short : I wanna get rid of every non-device contact (mainly gmail) from my device. So they won't shows up even if I use the search.

Long : So, I want to SAVE only my device contacts in my device. I want to get rid of all facebook and google contacts.

I've succeeded in unsync and removing facebook contacts. But it seems my google contact (the gmail contact) is still there, while not seen if I browsed through the contact, if I use the search feature (in contact) the gmail contact still shows up.

Checking or unchecking "show contact with phone number only" doesn't affect this at all. Neither with unchecking sync contacts via setting > account.

If I want to delete the contact, it said that the original source will also get deleted when sync turned on again.

Any idea??

Comment: Are you asking about where new contacts are saved, or showing & hiding existing contacts? It's not clear, as the start of your question mentions saving, but the rest talks about contacts "showing up" and deleting.

Comment: Not new contact. But existing ones. Saving the existing device contact only in device.

Comment: I have edited my post. Pls check it out